# Referencing configuration section from other place in spring-boot application.yaml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I'm configuring spring boot kafka streams in `application.yaml`. I need to configure properties of the output topics:

```yaml
producer:
  topic.properties:
    cleanup.policy: compact
    retention.ms: 604800000
```

Because I have the same configuration across the whole file I want to make single point where to define values:

```yaml
my:
 policy: compact
 retention: 604800000
producer:
  topic.properties:
    cleanup.policy: ${my.policy}
    retention.ms: ${my.retention}
```

But the `topic.properties` is just generic map passed to underlying kafka library. To make the configuration more flexible I would like to reference the `my` section from the `producer.topic.properties`. So when new kafka property is added then only `my` section is updated.

I tried:

```yaml
producer:
  topic.properties: ${my}
```

But this doesn't work - `${my}` is replaced by `my.toString()` and configuration fails on getting String where Map is expected.

I'm looking for some section placeholder. For example in OpenAPI Spec you can do something similar to:

```yaml
my:
 policy: compact
 retention: 604800000
producer:
  topic.properties:
     $ref: '/my'
```

I know basic YAML doesn't support references. But is there something in `spring-boot` allowing to reference other config sections?

Answer (score 1):

You can reference other properties, but one at a time:

```
my:
 policy: compact
 retention: 604800000
producer:
  topic.properties:
     policy: ${my.policy}
     retention: ${my.retention}
```